# send data to server when app is background

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an iOS app which interacts with BLE device. what I wanted to do is, app detects BLE device and gets info from it in background mode. After getting info from BLE in background mode, I want to send that info to server. how can i achieve this functionality.

Comment: Questions that ask "is it possible..." aren't good questions since the answer is either "yes" or "no".  In this case it is yes.  You should ask a question where you are having a specific issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this,

Keep one connection request alive in background, whenever your BLE device advertised your app should automatically connect with BLE device and getting information from your BLE device as per your services implementation. After getting data from BLE device you can send that data via web service using background task.